# How to make multithreads code with 2 loops

Tags: java, multithreading, loops

I trying to make my code faster with multi-threads.
I have 2 bigs arrays (in my code above I put small arrays for the example).

This is my code that I tryied, but its stuck and not make anything:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    private ArrayList<String> blackList = new ArrayList<String>();

    String[] cities = {
        "London",
        "Paris",
        "Barcelona"
    };

    String[] cats = {
        "Animals",
        "Jobs",
        "Env",
        "B"
    };
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.run();
    }
    
    public void run() {
        ExecutorService svc = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        int chunks = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        
        long iterationsCities = cities.length;
        long iterationsCats = cats.length;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < chunks; ++i) {
            int startCities = (int) (iterationsCities / chunks * i);
            int endCities = (int) (iterationsCities / chunks * (i + 1));
            
            int startCats = (int) (iterationsCats / chunks * i);
            int endCats = (int) (iterationsCats / chunks * (i + 1));
            
            svc.execute(new Task(startCities, endCities, startCats, endCats));
        }
        
    }

    public class Task implements Runnable {
        int startCities; 
        int endCities; 
        int startCats; 
        int endCats;
        
        public Task(int startCities, int endCities, int startCats, int endCats) {
            this.startCities = startCities;
            this.endCities = endCities; 
            this.startCats = startCats; 
            this.endCats = endCats;
        }
        
        public void launch() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            for(int i=startCities; i<endCities; i++)
            {
                for(int j=startCats; j<endCats; j++)
                {
                    String link = "https://.../pro/search/" + cats[j] + "/" + cities[i];
                    //System.out.println(link);

                    HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
                    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                            .uri(URI.create(link))
                            .GET() 
                            .build();

                    HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request,
                            HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

                    //System.out.println(link);
                    String html = response.body();

                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("data-count=\"([A-Za-z0-9_]*)\"");
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);
                    boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
                    if(matchFound)
                    {
                        int dataCount = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
                        if(dataCount == 0)
                        {
                            String l = cats[j] + "/" + cities[i];
                            if(!blackList.contains(l)) {
                                blackList.add(l);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                launch();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

My code makes http request, gets value in the meta tag of the HTML and asks if the value equal to 0, if yes it saves the URL in the blacklist.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Maybe add some console output/logging to see what's going on. And verify your program is running single threaded as desired (`chunks=1`)

Comment: The question needs work. As asked, it's debugging. FWIW,  `iterationsCats / chunks * i` should be `(iterationsCats * i) / chunks` (parentheses optional, but a good idea).

Comment: Now i got error:
java.net.ConnectException: Address already in use: no further information on client.send line